# javascript document.getElementById changing .value to .href not working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm using a previous script to replace Quicktime videos. 
The original script uses buttons to load the URL of the other videos but I want to use simple links.  This is where my extremely limited knowledge of javascript has got me stuck.

I thought I could change the "**.value**" to "**.href**" in this code:

```
function loadVideo() {
                movie.loadURL( document.getElementById('movie-url').value );
                readyInitialized = false;
            }
```

but the video opens in a separate window.

My links are as follows:

```
<a id="movie-url" href="http://www.fixxed.com/test/test/media/Kodak_FashionShow.mov" onclick="loadVideo(); return false;" rel="nofollow">Second Video</a><br />
<a id="movie-url" href="http://www.fixxed.com/test/test/media/doritos-day.mov" onclick="loadVideo(); return false;" rel="nofollow">Frist Video</a>
```

Clicking on any of those links above just triggers this:

```
<input type="text" id="movie-url" value="http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/Building_On_The_Past.mov" />
```

The HTML document AND the javascript file both contain similar javascript code and won't work without the other (I don't know why, I'd like to just use it once)
HTML:

```
function loadVideo() {
                movie.loadURL( document.getElementById('movie-url').value );
                readyInitialized = false;
            }
```

javascript file:

```
pfQuicktime.prototype.loadURL = function() {
    if (this.movie) {
        var url = document.getElementById('movie-url').value;
        this.movie.SetURL(url);
        this.movie.SetControllerVisible(false);
    }
}
```

A working example can be found [HERE](http://www.fixxed.com/test/test/test.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the href of the element then you'll want to use `getAttribute('href')` such that:

```
function loadVideo() {
           movie.loadURL( document.getElementById('movie-url').getAttribute('href'));
           readyInitialized = false;
         }
```

Also as Alnitak has pointed out, you cannot use an ID more than once on a page.

Comment: caution - the `href` _attribute_ can be relative (i.e. it's what's in the markup) but the `href` _property_ will be absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You're suffering from having too many elements (i.e. more than one) having the same ID.

Give each element its own ID, and in the event handler use `this` to refer to the current element, so you can extract its `href`:

```
<a id="movie1" href="http://..../"  
 onclick="loadVideo(this);" rel="nofollow"">First</a><br />

<a id="movie2" href="http://..../"
 onclick="loadVideo(this);" rel="nofollow">Second</a>

<script>
function loadVideo() {
    movie.loadURL(this.href);
    readyInitialized = false;
    return false;
}

// this _may_ allow you to supply your own URL
pfQuicktime.prototype.loadURL = function(url) {
    if (this.movie) {
        this.movie.SetURL(url);
        this.movie.SetControllerVisible(false);
    }
}

</script>
```

(FWIW, I wouldn't normally suggest using DOM0 inline event handlers, but it seems convenient in this case).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but how do I change the other code to make it all work? **var url = document.getElementById('movie-url').value;**

Comment: @rod I added some code - the `pfQuicktime` module isn't intended to let you change the URL, but the modified version might.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I really appreciate your help though.